# Oracle - Performing operation on each row of result set

Tags: sql, oracle, ssrs-2008

I need help with a query. The query returns a column of all the views in the database. My ultimate goal is to have the whole result set be one column containing all the views in the database, and the other column containing how many records/rows are present in each corresponding table.

This:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OWNER, 
       OBJECT_NAME 
 FROM DBA_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'VIEW'
  AND OWNER = 'ADMIN'
```

returns the first column however I can't seem to find a way to combine it with :

```
select count(*) from view_X
```

to get the second column of the result set.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to know how many rows a view will return or how many rows are in each (or all) base tables? `how many records/rows are present in each corresponding table`. does not correspond to `select count(*) from view_X`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some XML magic, this can be done with a single statement:

```
select object_name as view_name,
       to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from "'||owner||'"."'||object_name||'"')),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) as row_count
from dba_objects
where object_type = 'VIEW'
  and owner = 'ADMIN'
order by 1;
```

Comment: This is great !! Thank you guys for the responses. However this is for a report in SSRS 2008 and when I plug in the code into the query designer, it gives me an 'Invalid character' error. Pretty sure its coming from the "to_number..." line but not sure where and why. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1964821: no idea, never used this SSRS tool.

Answer (score 2):

This is a toughie. You can't join to the `select count(*) from view_X` or anything like that using straight SQL, so the best thing I can think of is a function that takes a view name and returns its count:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ViewRowCount(viewName VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
AS
  rowCount NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || viewName INTO rowCount;
  RETURN rowCount;
END;
/
```

Once the function is in place you can call it from your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OWNER, 
       OBJECT_NAME,
       ViewRowCount(OBJECT_NAME)
 FROM DBA_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'VIEW'
  AND OWNER = 'ADMIN';
```

BTW, I don't think you need the `DISTINCT` for this query, but I don't have DBA access today so I can't be sure. The record counting will be slow enough as it is, so if there are duplicates before filtering with `DISTINCT` there will be a count for every duplicate row, making it even slower.

---

Also take a look at Rachcha's solution, which doesn't need to create a new object (the function) like mine does. If you'll be calling from a front-end you'll need to use something like my answer, but if you'll be calling from SQL*Plus Rachcha's will work very well.

Answer (score 2):

Ed Gibbs has provided a comprehensive answer.
I have the following solution for what you are looking for.

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
    x INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (SELECT 'ADMIN' AS owner, object_name
                FROM all_objects
               WHERE object_type = 'VIEW'
                 AND owner = 'ADMIN') LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('SELECT count(*) FROM ' || i.object_name) INTO x;
        dbms_output.put_line (i.owner || ' | ' || i.object_name || ' | ' || x);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: +1 Rachcha - very nice. I like how you don't need to create a new object with your solution.

Comment: @Ed Gibbs, thanks! If I had this problem I would implement your solution instead, especially when I have to generate a report.

Answer (score 0):

Take at [cursors](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html) in Oracle.  They let you loop over a result set.  Once you do that, you can dynamically execute sql of the form:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ''' || OBJECT_NAME || ''' count(*) FROM ' || OBJECT_NAME'
```

for each view in your list.

Comment: I don't think that that is valid Oracle syntax.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Not on its own.  I changed it to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE but the general gist was to show how to form a string using a view name.  He will have to use a cursor and loop through to run this statement for each view but this is the general gist of what he should execute each time.

Comment: It's still not valid Oracle syntax, regardless of any preceding code, this line will throw a syntax error.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Ah, forgot Oracle uses || instead of +.